# jquery tools, two references to identical library in order to make a script work

Tags: jquery, reference

I have a Wordpress theme with some functionality which depends on the jquery library jquery.tools. In my header file:

```
//header.php

<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#trigger-button-53").tooltip({effect:'slide'});
  })
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#accordion-slider').kwicks({  
    max : 750,  
    spacing : 1
});  
  });
</script>
```

And in my custom functions.php file:

```
// functions.php
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {

    wp_enqueue_script('tools', 'http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js', '', '', true );  
    $kwicks_url = get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-kwicks-1.5.1.js';
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-kwicks', $kwicks_url, '', '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js", '', '', true );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method'); // For use on the Front end (ie.    Theme)

?>
```

And both methods return:
    http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js?ver=3.4.2

As it stands, in this way all my javascript methods work a charm. But I'm referencing

```
http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js
```

twice to get it all to work? If I omit the direct reference in the header.php file, my scripts won't work even though both methods successfully load the library. Moreover, we shouldn't paste direct references to scripts in the header file of a WP theme (child theme to be specific) as this is bad practice. You may have noticed I'm loading the scripts in the footer when using the

```
my_scripts_method();
```

but it makes no difference if I load them in the header. Going off at a tangent slightly, I'm assuming that:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
 $handle
,$src
,$deps
,$ver
,$in_footer 
);
```

$handle could be any string i.e.

```
wp_enqueue_script('fried-egg', 'http://example.com/path/to/jquery.js');    
wp_enqueue_script('tools', 'http://example.com/path/to/jquery.js');
```

would equally be valid?

WTF's goin on? :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jQuery is loaded only *before* jQuery tools. If you load jQuery afterwards, any references to jQuery plugins will be overwritten by the new version of jQuery. This is why you are having to include jQuery tools twice (once before jQuery is overwritten, removing references to jQuery tools, and then again after jQuery is included again).

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js", '', '', true );
wp_enqueue_script('tools', 'http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js', '', '', true );  
$kwicks_url = get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-kwicks-1.5.1.js';
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-kwicks', $kwicks_url, '', '', true);
```

Comment: @AndrewCookson: Hmm, what does the generated HTML look like? The markup that's ultimately rendered in the browser, that is.

Comment: @A Whitaker: hi Andrew and thanks for your help. I put the calls to kwicks() & tooltip() in the footer, made the my_scripts_method() load libraries in the header, and bingo! it works. So order matters which is pretty logical really. You provided the clue though. Thanks again.